# Find current version in google app android

Tags: android, google-play, version

I need some help. Currently on Google play web there are apps such as Faccebook. In the Current Version section is "Varies with device". I want to know what version of the App that Current Version is in, and what is it? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this and you will get the details.

Inside OnCreate method write below code..

```
VersionChecker versionChecker = new VersionChecker();
    try {
        latestVersion = versionChecker.execute().get();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), latestVersion , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this gives you play store version of app..

then you have to check app version as below

```
PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
    PackageInfo info = null;
    try {
        info = manager.getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    assert info != null;
    version = info.versionName;
```

after that you can compare it with store version and setup your own update screens

```
if(version.equals(latestVersion)){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Update" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Update" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

And add VersionChecker.class as below

```
public class VersionChecker extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String newVersion;

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        try {
            newVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + "package name" + "&hl=en")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com")
                    .get()
                    .select(".hAyfc .htlgb")
                    .get(7)
                    .ownText();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return newVersion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the text says, it "varies with device". Different phones/tablets/devices will get different versions. There is no such thing as the current version.

If you want to know the version for a particular device, connect with the Play app on that device.